# Java assert bound on generic type

Tags: java, generics

I want to pass my type parameter to be used further, where it needs to be in some bounds. My current parameter doesn't fit these bounds, but during the runtime I checked it, and am really sure it actually has them. How can I tell Java that this is the case?

Example:

```
public abstract class Entity {
    // ...
}

public interface Adapter<T> {
    // ...
}

public class MyAdapter<E extends Entity> implements Adapter<E> {
    // ...
}

public <T> Adapter<T> getAdapter(Class<T> clazz, T entity) {
    if (Entity.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) {
        return new MyAdapter<T>(entity);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("I am really sure this never happens!");
    }
}
```

The problem is: I cannot change the `getAdapter` - method to add a constraint on `T`, as it is part of an interface I have to implement for a framework I am using. That's why I check, whether the given Class of T is actually within its bound of being a subclass of `Entity`, and then want to rightfully instantiate my own adapter class with a type parameter which is now known to be in its bounds. However, the compiler still complains that `Type Parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should extend 'Entity'`.

Can I somehow circumvent this?

Comment: `extends Adapter<T>` does not compile since it's an interface.

Comment: Also, the `T` in `extends `Adapter<T>` refers to a type parameter that doesn't exist in this signature.  Did you mean `implements Adapter<E>` ?

Comment: you are right, I screwed these parts up in my example. It is fixed now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MyAdapter` has a constructor that accepts `E`, you can cast both `entity` and the  result of the constructor.

```
return (Adapter<T>) new MyAdapter<>((Entity) entity);
```

Of course, these casts are considered unchecked since they happen at runtime, when the generic type information is gone.

Comment: Thank you, that solution is easier than I feared. Both of these casts should never fail in my given case, right?

Comment: @ErikBrendel Indeed it looks like in your case it should not fail.